# SCP Neo deployment - java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

I am deploying a java app in Sap Cloud Platform, Neo environment. When I try to activate it, I got the issues below:

```
2020 03 31 20:21:24#+0100#ERROR#OpenEJB.tomcat##anonymous#localhost-startStop-2#na#N/A#N/A#N/A##na#na#na#na#Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/anaplan-inbound-application] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet filter class: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2333)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2024)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:384)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:420)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1037)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1281)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5063)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:83)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2330)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
|
2020 03 31 20:21:24#+0100#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase##anonymous#localhost-startStop-2#na#N/A#N/A#N/A##na#na#na#na#ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/anaplan-inbound-application]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:845)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1651)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1631)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1312)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5063)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|
2020 03 31 20:21:24#+0100#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase##anonymous#localhost-startStop-2#na#N/A#N/A#N/A##na#na#na#na#ContainerBase.addChild: start:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/anaplan-inbound-application]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet filter class: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1315)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5063)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet filter class: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2333)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2024)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:384)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:420)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1037)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1281)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:83)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2330)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
|
2020 03 31 20:21:24#+0100#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig##anonymous#localhost-startStop-2#na#N/A#N/A#N/A##na#na#na#na#Error deploying web application archive [C:\\temp\\neo-javaee7_1.66.8\\server\\webapps\\anaplan-inbound-application.war] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/anaplan-inbound-application]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My POM file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>Anaplan Inbound Interface - Application</name>
    <description>Anaplan Inbound Interface - Application</description>

    <groupId>com.sunstar</groupId>
    <artifactId>anaplan-inbound-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sunstar</groupId>
        <artifactId>anaplan-inbound</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <!-- if you are behind a proxy use the following two properties to configure your proxy. Default: None -->
        <proxy.host/>
        <proxy.port/>
        <non.proxy.hosts/>

        <!-- Properties that are related to the SAP Cloud Platform. -->
        <scp.sdkVersion>1.44.12</scp.sdkVersion>

        <!-- this is the location of your local SAP CP Neo runtime -->
        <scp.sdkInstallPath>${project.basedir}/scp/sdk-${scp.sdkVersion}</scp.sdkInstallPath>
        <scp.sdkLocalServerContentPath>${project.basedir}/localServerContent</scp.sdkLocalServerContentPath>
        <scp.sdkErpEndpoint>
            ${scp.sdkInstallPath}/server/config_master/service.destinations/destinations/ErpQueryEndpoint
        </scp.sdkErpEndpoint>

        <scp.sdkSymbolicLink>${project.basedir}/scp/sdk</scp.sdkSymbolicLink>
        <scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>.sh</scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>
        <scp.sdkNeoCmd>${scp.sdkInstallPath}/tools/neo${scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension}</scp.sdkNeoCmd>
        <scp.sdkLocalServer>${scp.sdkInstallPath}/server</scp.sdkLocalServer>

        <scp.skipInstallSdk>false</scp.skipInstallSdk>
        <scp.skipDeploy>false</scp.skipDeploy>
        <scp.skipPutDestination>false</scp.skipPutDestination>
        <scp.skipRestart>false</scp.skipRestart>
        <scp.skipRollingUpdate>true</scp.skipRollingUpdate>

        <scp.vmArguments/>
        <scp.vmSize>lite</scp.vmSize>
        <scp.vmMinProcesses>1</scp.vmMinProcesses>
        <scp.vmMaxProcesses>1</scp.vmMaxProcesses>

        <scp.app/>
        <scp.host/>
        <scp.account/>
        <scp.username/>
        <scp.password/>

        <!-- Required for SAP CP user session management and audit logging. -->
        <scp.warImportPackage>
            com.sap.security.auth.service,com.sap.security.um.service.api,com.sap.core.service.auditlog.impl,com.sap.cloud.auditlog,com.sap.cloud.auditlog.exception,com.sap.cloud.auditlog.extension
        </scp.warImportPackage>

        <!-- Defines whether the deployment is productive or not. -->
        <productive/>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>scp-neo</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana</groupId>
            <artifactId>s4hana-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo-javaee7-wp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        commented out to get VDM getters -->
        <!--         <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--    custom VDM-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--     custom VDM   -->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                        <archive>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                                <Import-Package>${scp.warImportPackage}</Import-Package>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                        <webResources>
                            <resources>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resources>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
                                <artifactId>neo-javaee7-wp-sdk</artifactId>
                                <version>${scp.sdkVersion}</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${scp.sdkInstallPath}</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Plugin for deployment to SAP Cloud Platform Neo. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo-javaee7-wp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${scp.sdkVersion}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipRestart}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipDeploy}</skip>
                                <vmArguments>${scp.vmArguments}</vmArguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipRestart}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>rolling-update</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>rolling-update</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipRollingUpdate}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdkInstallPath>${scp.sdkInstallPath}</sdkInstallPath>
                        <skip>${scp.skipInstallSdk}</skip>

                        <application>${scp.app}</application>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</source>

                        <vmArguments>${scp.vmArguments}</vmArguments>
                        <size>${scp.vmSize}</size>
                        <minimumProcesses>${scp.vmMinProcesses}</minimumProcesses>
                        <maximumProcesses>${scp.vmMaxProcesses}</maximumProcesses>

                        <host>${scp.host}</host>
                        <account>${scp.account}</account>
                        <user>${scp.username}</user>
                        <password>${scp.password}</password>
                        <synchronous>true</synchronous>

                        <httpProxyHost>${proxy.host}</httpProxyHost>
                        <httpProxyPort>${proxy.port}</httpProxyPort>
                        <httpsProxyHost>${proxy.host}</httpsProxyHost>
                        <httpsProxyPort>${proxy.port}</httpsProxyPort>

                        <consoleCommand/>
                        <consoleHttpProxyHost>${proxy.host}</consoleHttpProxyHost>
                        <consoleHttpProxyPort>${proxy.port}</consoleHttpProxyPort>
                        <consoleHttpsProxyHost>${proxy.host}</consoleHttpsProxyHost>
                        <consoleHttpsProxyPort>${proxy.port}</consoleHttpsProxyPort>

                        <dbsystem/>
                        <dbSize/>
                        <dbUser/>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Plugin for deployment to local runtime of SAP Cloud Platform Neo. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scp-neo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdkPlugin>neo-javaee7-wp-maven-plugin</sdkPlugin>
                        <sdkPluginVersion>${scp.sdkVersion}</sdkPluginVersion>
                        <sdkInstallPath>${scp.sdkInstallPath}</sdkInstallPath>
                        <sdkSymbolicLink>${scp.sdkSymbolicLink}</sdkSymbolicLink>
                        <sdkServerContentPath>${scp.sdkLocalServerContentPath}</sdkServerContentPath>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</source>
                        <proxyHost>${proxy.host}</proxyHost>
                        <proxyPort>${proxy.port}</proxyPort>
                        <httpNonProxyHosts>${non.proxy.hosts}</httpNonProxyHosts>
                        <destinations>
                            <destination>
                                <path>${scp.sdkErpEndpoint}</path>
                                <username>${erp.username}</username>
                                <password>${erp.password}</password>
                                <url>${erp.url}</url>
                            </destination>
                        </destinations>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>s4sdk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <generateSalt>true</generateSalt>
                            <salt>92f0edd41f03467b59950612780423cf28722270f1ab59c3422ec9070f805763</salt>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--            Custom VDM-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel</groupId>
                <artifactId>odata-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<!--                <version>2.9.1</version>-->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-consumption</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputDirectory>${project.basedir}/edmx</inputDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/vdm</outputDirectory>
                            <deleteOutputDirectory>true</deleteOutputDirectory>
                            <packageName>com.sunstar.vdm</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--            custom VDM-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/vdm</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <!--
        Profiles that are used to set the Neo SDK "neo" command extension ("neo.sh" or "neo.cmd")
        -->
        <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>.bat</scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>unix</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>.sh</scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- Profile setting properties for deploying to the local SAP CP runtime. -->
        <profile>
            <id>local-deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>!scp.app</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.skipInstallSdk>true</scp.skipInstallSdk>
                <scp.skipDeploy>true</scp.skipDeploy>
                <scp.skipPutDestination>true</scp.skipPutDestination>
                <scp.skipRestart>true</scp.skipRestart>
                <scp.skipRollingUpdate>true</scp.skipRollingUpdate>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- Profile setting properties for deploying a productive version to SAP CP. -->
        <profile>
            <id>scp-deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>productive</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.skipInstallSdk>false</scp.skipInstallSdk>
                <scp.skipDeploy>true</scp.skipDeploy>
                <scp.skipPutDestination>false</scp.skipPutDestination>
                <scp.skipRestart>true</scp.skipRestart>
                <scp.skipRollingUpdate>false</scp.skipRollingUpdate>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I adapted the POM file to use Cloud SDK v3, but I am not sure if there is any relation to the issue above.

Would you guys give me any hint on how to solve this issue?

BR,
Pietro

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project form the archetype "scp-neo-javaee7" to get the last version. Then, I moved all the objects to the new project.

Now I was able to deploy it in SCP Neo.